# How to repaint in qt without removing the previous paint in the widget?

Tags: windows, macos, qt

Every time I repaint on the QWidget it gets repainted and deletes the previous paint. How can I save the previous state while performing repainting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it explicitly. One way would be to paint on a `QImage`, and then in the `paintEvent` simply blit the contents to the widget.

A much simpler approach is to store all the graphic primitives in a container of some sort, and paint them all as needed. Qt provides just such a container: `QPicture` is a graphic metafile that stores graphical operations for later replay.

For example:

```
class PicLabel : public QLabel {
  QPicture m_picture;
public:
  PicLabel(const QString & text, QWidget * parent = 0) :
    QLabel(text, parent) {}
  PicLabel(QWidget * parent = 0) : QLabel(parent) {}
  void addPoint(const QPointF & point) {
    QPainter p(&m_picture);
    p.drawPoint(point);
    update();
  }
  void addLine(const QPointF & start, const QPointF & end) {
    QPainter p(&m_picture);
    p.drawLine(start, end);
    update();
  }
  void clear() {
    std::swap(m_picture, QPicture());
    update();
  }
protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
    QLabel::paintEvent(event);
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawPicture(0, 0, m_picture);
  }
};
```

Comment: the situation is like this: on mouse click over the Qlabel I paint a point, then if I click again the first point is removed. I want to keep them both.

Comment: @Programming This will only work for a label that has fixed size, and whose text never changes. In such a case, you can `render()` the label *once* into an image, when the label is first shown. Every time after that, you can add the point onto the image. This is till a very complex way of going about it. You shouldn't do it.

Comment: but what do you suggest then?

Comment: Yes but after I paint one point, and then perform an update(), the previous points are deleted.

Comment: But is there any other way without saving the previous painted area ? I think there should be any attribute that enables repainting without erasing the previous painted areas...

Comment: @Programming "after I paint one point, and then perform an update(), the previous points are deleted" No, they are not. Try out the code I posted and you'll see. What you're trying to do is to store a large bitmap of your widget, with a size possibly on the order of megabytes, instead of storing a small vector of point coordinates.

Comment: @Programming There is really no concept of "saving" the previously painted area, in a general sense. Remember: the widget may need to be repainted at any time, for any reason, *from scratch* - meaning that whatever previous content was there is inapplicable. How do you want it to behave when you change the text of the label? Or its style? Or if the application, or system-wide style is changed? Your `QLabel` requires a fresh repaint whenever you change settings in the control panel. Or possibly due to accessibility settings.

Comment: @Programming  Remember: you *do not* have full control over when the widget needs to be repainted from scratch. So you'll be fighting a pointless battle if you assume otherwise.

Comment: but what if I paint a polygon or ellipse?

Comment: @Programming Well, then store the information for a polygon or an ellipse. You might be much better off using `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView` - they store all of the graphic items for you. If not, you'd probably want to paint on a `QPicture` - an in-memory metafile, essentially, and simply paint that picture in the paint event. It'll usually take much less memory than a `QImage`, and should perform better.

Comment: so you mean there is no flag or smth like this that repaints on the previous state??

Comment: @Programming No, because it's impossible to implement such a flag, in the general case. Remember: at some point in time, the background and the text of the label might need to change without the label having any control over it. How will you repaint all your points/ellipses/polygons if you have to clear the image and start over? Think about that.